# Is there an RXJS standard for creating/handling HTTP streams?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Simply put, I constantly hit roadblocks with RXJS because almost every example relies on a constant stream of data whereas I'm making HTTP requests that are singular in nature.

My common scenario is as such: I have a service that makes API calls and updates the necessary consumers. In my head, it's like simple event emitting. The subscribers connect and wait for the event - once they get it, they go off and do their own thing separately.

The problem, as I'm sure you're aware, is that HTTP subscriptions terminate immediately upon completion and to "connect" triggers it immediately. It's a concept of RXJS that I still struggle to wrap my head around.

So when you throw in concurrent calls to the method, consumers relying on other consumers, forkjoins and asynchronous hell - I've tried all sorts of abominations involving Subjects, replays, shared maps. I've ultimately settled on something like so:

```
myBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Result>(null);
myBehaviorSubject$ = myBehaviorSubject.asObservable()
...
getData(params): Observable<Result[]> {
      const http$ = this.httpClient
        .get('blah', {params})
        .pipe(map(response => response as Result[]));

      http$.subscribe(result: Result => {
         myBehaviorSubject.next(result);
      });

      return myBehaviorSubject$;
    }
```

It feels...*wrong*. I know things like mergeMap handle internal subscriptions similarly and higher order observables aren't anti-pattern, but I can't help but think I'm just doing it wrong.

Is internal subscriptions really the way to do this? Are there ways too keep consumers waiting for HTTP requests without making redundant calls to the server?

Can anyone shed some light on this matter?

Comment: I do not think there is anything fundamentally wrong in what you do.
The only thing I would do is to substitute BehaviorSubject with a simple either a Subject or a ReplaySubject. The latter in case you want to cache the result of the call for consumers that subscribe to the Obsvable after the http call has been made.

Answer (score 0):

I go against the norm with http requests.  They aren't streams to me.

```
async getData(params): Promise<Result[]> {
    return this.httpClient
        .get('blah', {params})
        .toPromise();       
}
```

Or:

```
async loadComplexViewModelData(params): Promise<{[dataA, dataB, dataC]}> {    
  [dataA, dataB, dataC] = await Promise.all([
    this.httpClient
      .get('blahA', {params})
      .toPromise();
    this.httpClient
      .get('blahB', {params})
       .toPromise();
    this.httpClient
      .get('blahC', {params})
      .toPromise();
  ]);      
}
```

Above doesn't include error handling or nesting..  Maybe request `blahB` returns keys you then need to fetch.  Append a `then()` statement to `toPromise()`.

This is an alternative that is contrary to popular pattern and does't specifically answer stated question.

This is how I solved the "It feels...wrong" delima I had as well. I don't think rxjs is the right tool for the job, and I am in the minority :)